# Custom Security Code in cakephp not display

Tags: cakephp

I have this code in my wordpress site.
which is in contact us page.

```
<img src="securitycode/SecurityImages.p?characters=5" border="0"  alt="Security code" />
```

I also uploaded

```
 webroot\fonts\monofont.ttf
  \app\View\Elements\forms\securitycode\SecurityImages.php
```

How to convert that code in cakephp format..

Answer (score 0):

**In CakePHP**

```
HtmlHelper::image(string $path, array $options = array())
```

Parameters:

`$path (string)` – Path to the image.

`$options (array)` – An array of html attributes.

So, for your code looks like

```
echo $this->Html->image("securitycode/SecurityImages.p?characters=5", array(
    "alt" => "Security code",
    "border"="0"
));
```

Comment: Still i cant see the security code, This is the code SecurityImages.php

<?php
putenv('GDFONTPATH='.realpath('.'));
session_start();
.......................................
?>

Comment: I want that security code , so that my form are limited to spam,, they must fill up the code, before the form will successfully submitted

Comment: why not you use  cakephp captcha. look this  http://www.devarticles.in/cakephp/simple-captcha-component-for-cakephp/